# RSolve and a recurrence relation

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

In the book *An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms* there is a recurrence relation for the number of compares used in Quicksort algorithm:
$$ C_N=N+1+\sum_{0≤k≤N-1}\frac{1}{N}(C_k+C_{N−k−1}) $$
(See http://aofa.cs.princeton.edu/10analysis/ for details)

This recurrence relation is already solved in the book:
$$ C_N = 2(N+1)H_N - 2N,$$
where $ H_N $ are harmonic numbers.

Now I'm trying to solve it using *Mathematica*:

```
RSolve[{c[n] == n + 1 + 1/n*Sum[c[k] + c[n - k - 1], {k, 0, n - 1}], 
        c[0] == 0}, c[n], n]
```

Unfortunately, I can't get a result: `RSolve` just pretty prints input and doesn't solve anything.

Is there any way to solve such recurrences using *Mathematica*?
Are there any other CASes which able to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `c[n]` with

```
c[n_] := c[n] = n + 1 + 1/n*Sum[c[k] + c[n - k - 1], {k, 0, n - 1}]
c[0] = 0;
```

and then use [`FindSequenceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find the desired solution:

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[c[n], {n, 1, 10}], n]
```

> ```
> 2 (1 + n) (-1 + EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 2 + n])
> ```

```
FullSimplify@%
```

> ```
> 2 (1 + n) (-1 + HarmonicNumber[1 + n])
> ```

```
%% == 2 (n + 1) HarmonicNumber[n] - 2 n // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Dear Karsten, small question: what if instead of the condition c[0]=0 we had one of the kind c[n<2]=0, how do we express this in mathematica when defining and solving recurrence relations as you have exactly done in the above. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: @user929304 You can use a [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html), a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html), or [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html).

Comment: In my answer I could have used, e. g., `c[n_?(# <= 0 &)] = 0;`, `c[n_ /; n <= 0] = 0;`, or `c[n_] /; n <= 0 := c[n] = 0;` instead of `c[0] = 0;` or just `c[n_] := c[n] = \[Piecewise] {
    {0, n <= 0},
    {n + 1 + 1/n*Sum[c[k] + c[n - k - 1], {k, 0, n - 1}], n > 0}
   }` for both cases.